# Skip from Activity A to C when list in B contains just 1 item

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin

My app has 3 levels of activity's.
I'll call them A, B and C.

A and B contain listview, C something else.
When I choose an item in A, B opens and shows a list with one or more options.

When this list in B only contains 1 item, it's useless to make the user choose which one he wants to view, so the app should instead just skip to C.

I managed to do this by checking if there is just 1 item in the list, and if so it loads C with the correct info. But while this happens, activity B is visible for a short moment, which is rather ugly.

I've tried skipping the SetContentView if there was just 1 item in the list, but when I navigate back to B from C, I get a nullpointer exception because some stuff hasn't be initialized.

Is there any correct way to skip through an activity, but being able to navigate back to it?

Comment: Why don't you start `Activity C` directly from `A` when there is only one item in `Activity B`?

Comment: can you show some code what are u doing in A to jump C?

Comment: @JoelFernandes Because when I go back 'up' from C, I do have to be in Activity B instead of jumping back to A again.

Comment: @keshav When I'm in A I jump to B, then in B the list is filled using a webservice, when the data is retrieved, and there is only 1 item, C is opened.

Comment: @Devin19 You need to check the list in A not in B them jump from A to C when there is only one item not through B.

Comment: @keshav yea I've thought about doing that, but how do I get in B when I go back from C? Because I need to be able to add items to the list in B when I go back from C

Comment: How are u adding items in B means when its updated?

Comment: @keshav The webservice can return over 100 items, so I´m not showing all of them by default. Because many users only use a few of them. But in B there is a + button so you can choose items in this full list to add to the list in B. 
If someone only picks one, it can skip from A to C because else it would require another action by the user to go to C while there is just one option to choose from.
But when they come back from C, they need to be able to click the + item in B if they want to add extra items to their ´quicklist´ in B.
I hope this the reason behind my question a bit more clear.

Comment: In this case its better to move through B, you don't need to skip it anytime because you are giving option to add items in B .

Comment: @keshav Okay, but how do I move through B, without it being visible for a brief moment while passing through it?